# how to access the content of a HTML tag in Bash using XMLStarlet

Tags: html, xml, bash, xmlstarlet

I'm trying to learn how to access the content of HTML tags in Bash using XMLStarlet. As an example, I'm attempting to access some text in the page www.wisdomofchopra.com/iframe.php. I'm having some difficulty specifying the "address" of the content in the HTML for XMLStarlet and would value some assistance. My code attempt is below:

```
URL="http://www.wisdomofchopra.com/iframe.php"
webPage="$(curl -s "${URL}")"
echo "${webPage}" | xmlstarlet sel -T -t -c "//html/body//table/tr/td[@id='quote']/header/h2/"
```

This produces the following output:

```
-:29.12: Opening and ending tag mismatch: meta line 5 and head
    </head>
           ^
-:35.100: Entity 'nbsp' not defined
te"><header><h2>&quot;Emotional intelligence is beyond total reality&quot;&nbsp;
                                                                               ^
-:35.106: Entity 'nbsp' not defined
eader><h2>&quot;Emotional intelligence is beyond total reality&quot;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                                               ^
-:41.119: EntityRef: expecting ';'
witter.com/intent/tweet?original_referer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wisdomofchopra.com&via
                                                                               ^
-:41.139: EntityRef: expecting ';'
eet?original_referer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wisdomofchopra.com&via=WisdomOfChopra&text
                                                                               ^
-:41.196: EntityRef: expecting ';'
via=WisdomOfChopra&text=%27Emotional+intelligence+is+beyond+total+reality%27&url
                                                                               ^
-:52.169: EntityRef: expecting ';'
));document.write(' src="http://ads.adbrite.com/mb/text_group.php?sid=2171164&zs
                                                                               ^
-:52.186: EntityRef: expecting ';'
(' src="http://ads.adbrite.com/mb/text_group.php?sid=2171164&zs=3436385f3630&ifr
                                                                               ^
-:52.209: EntityRef: expecting ';'
ite.com/mb/text_group.php?sid=2171164&zs=3436385f3630&ifr='+AdBrite_Iframe+'&ref
                                                                               ^
-:53.99: EntityRef: expecting ';'
p" href="http://www.adbrite.com/mb/commerce/purchase_form.php?opid=2171164&afsid
                                                                               ^
-:57.9: Opening and ending tag mismatch: head line 3 and html
</html>
       ^
-:58.1: Premature end of data in tag html line 2
```

---

EDIT: For convenience, below is some roughly-equivalent HTML code for the web page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Your random fictional Deepak Chopra quote:</h3>
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="128" align="left" valign="top"><img src="img/imageSmall2.png" width="80" height="80" /></td>
                <td id="quote"><header><h2>&quot;Perceptual reality serves total truth&quot;&nbsp;&nbsp;</h2></header></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't think this is the problem. I've created a cut-down bit of code that is hierarchically similar to the example web page and I still run into similar problems. I've added this cut-down version to the post text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get XMLStarlet to cope with the HTML, so I just did it using grep and AWK:

```
printDeepakChopraAdvice(){
    URL="http://www.wisdomofchopra.com/iframe.php"
    webPage="$(curl -s "${URL}")"
    text="$(echo "${webPage}" | grep "id=\"quote\"" | awk -F"&quot;" '{print $2}')"
    echo "${text}"
}
```